# Where should I be getting my release files from when using git?

Tags: git, release

Maybe its a weird question but I'm still pretty inexperienced with git. Basically I finished writing a pretty simple Chrome extension. I've been using git during development to get the hang of using it, but I'm a little confused about how to actually generate the release. In my actual project folder there is a hidden .git folder that gets included when I pack the Chrome extension, and I don't want that. I know I can just copy the files to another directory and get rid of the git stuff, but is there a correct way from within git to be able to generate this kind of release directory with only my project files? Or rather, how should I be doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would normally have a `Makefile` or equivalent with a `dist` target that would pack things up and create the crx file when you do `make dist`. Packing things up is not git's responsibility, as it can't know the details of your project's structure.

Another helpful hint is having things in `src` subdirectory so that you can have other, non-source stuff around (like documentation, readmes, libraries, config skeletons, anything else that is not a source - most of these things do not apply to a Chrome extension). An added benefit is that `.git` directory wouldn't be in it :p

Answer (score 0):

Another (git) way would be to move .git completely *out of* your working tree.

- Set `GIT_DIR` to `/path/to/.git` (move your current `.git` folder there)
- Set `GIT_WORK_TREE` to `/path/to/your/workingtree`

And now any git command done within your worktree will still work, except the `.git` folder won't be there.

Comment: this is definitely possible, but i think it is more of a workaround than a real solution. it is nice to have this if you absolutely cannot have the .git folder at its default location, but i don't think this is the case here.